# Vulkan perspective matrix - not behaving as expected

Tags: java, vulkan

I am working through the excellent https://vulkan-tutorial.com/ and have reached the point where we are applying perspective and view transformations to the scene.

Here is the vertex shader as things stand:

```
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

layout(binding = 0) uniform View {
    mat4 projection;
    mat4 modelview;
} view;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 col;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 coords;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 fragColour;
layout(location = 1) out vec2 fragCoords;

void main() {
    gl_Position = view.projection * view.modelview * vec4(pos, 1.0);
    fragColour = col;
    fragCoords = coords;
}
```

We are rendering a simple indexed quad, the fragment shader simply outputs the `fragColour` so we get a nice coloured rectangle (ignores the sampler at the moment).

We initially set the two matrices in the uniform buffer to be identity so that we should get the same behaviour as the previous stage (without any uniforms) which we do - all good so far.

However when we attempt to apply the perspective and camera transformations we get nothing - not unusual during 3D development!
Initially we assumed that we had done something obviously wrong, or the camera was pointing the wrong way, etc.
But after a good few hours we still can't see what we've done wrong.

So we took a step back and reset the perspective to identity and visually tested the camera (or modelview) matrix.
If we (for example) apply an up/down or left/right transform the quad is displayed correctly displaced in whichever direction we tried.
Ditto for a rotation matrix.
So I conclude that the matrix class, the buffer code, and the descriptor binding for the uniform is all working correctly - the problem must be with the perspective matrix itself.

Here is the code that generates the perspective matrix:

```java
public Matrix matrix(float near, float far, Dimensions dim) {
    return new Matrix.Builder()
        .set(0, 0, 1f / (height * dim.ratio()))
        .set(1, 1, 1f / height)
        .set(2, 2, far / (near - far))
        .set(2, 3, -1)
        .set(3, 2, (near * far) / (near - far))
        .build();
}
```

This is from the Vulkan cookbook and compares fine with several other examples we have found online.
This *should* produce Z coords that will be in Vulkan 0..1 range after perspective division.

In the demo the matrix is created thus:

```java
final Matrix projection = Projection.DEFAULT.matrix(0.01f, 100f, new Dimensions(640, 480));
```

which generates:

```
   0.75000,   0.00000,   0.00000,   0.00000
   0.00000,   1.00000,   0.00000,   0.00000
   0.00000,   0.00000,  -1.00010,  -1.00000
   0.00000,   0.00000,  -0.01000,   0.00000
```

Does this look correct?

Note this is Java so no GLM!

If my maths is up to scratch this should move the quad to Z == -1 so I would expect it to be visible if the camera is at the origin looking in the negative Z direction (or if the camera matrix is identity).

But the only time we ever see anything is if we use:

```java
final Matrix projection = Projection.DEFAULT.matrix(0.01f, 100f, new Dimensions(640, 480));
cam.direction(Vector.Z_AXIS);
cam.move(new Vector(0, 0, -1));

or

final Matrix projection = Projection.DEFAULT.matrix(0.01f, 100f, new Dimensions(640, 480));
cam.direction(Vector.Z_AXIS.invert());
cam.move(new Vector(0, 0, +1));
```

In both cases the we see a small part of the quad filling the viewport. All other combinations result in nothing being displayed.

For the first case with the camera pointing in the Z direction and moved by Z -1 the camera matrix is:

```
  -1.00000,   0.00000,   0.00000,  -0.00000
   0.00000,   1.00000,  -0.00000,  -0.00000
  -0.00000,  -0.00000,  -1.00000,   0.00000
   0.00000,   0.00000,   0.00000,   1.00000
```

which looks fine to me.

Obviously I could provide a lot more code but my instinct is that there is something wrong with the perspective matrix - can anyone see any obvious errors with that matrix?

Couple of other possibly related notes:

- we have no depth test active (set to null in the pipeline)
- the viewport depth is set to the default min = 0 and max = 1
- I can't remember OpenGL being this difficult!

**EDIT:** View port with default 0..1 min/max depth:

```java
public ViewportStageBuilder viewport(Rectangle rect, float min, float max) {
    final ScreenCoordinate coords = rect.position();
    final Dimensions dim = rect.dimensions();
    final VkViewport viewport = new VkViewport();
    viewport.x = coords.x;
    viewport.y = coords.y;
    viewport.width = dim.width;
    viewport.height = dim.height;
    viewport.minDepth = min;
    viewport.maxDepth = max;
    viewports.add(viewport);
    return this;
}

public ViewportStageBuilder viewport(Rectangle rect) {
    return viewport(rect, 0, 1);
}

public ViewportStageBuilder scissor(Rectangle rect) {
    scissors.add(new VkRect2D(rect));
    return this;
}
```

where `rect` is the swap-chain extent (640 x 480).

**EDIT:** RenderDoc analysis:

I had already downloaded RenderDoc and got it working this morning against my demo application. Here are the vertices input to the shader in the `VS In` view:

VTX     IDX     pos

0       0       -0.50 -0.50 0.00

1       1       -0.50  0.50 0.00

2       2        0.50 -0.50 0.00

3       3        0.50  0.50 0.00

and we can see these in the cross-hatch view.

`VS Out` looks like this:

VTX     IDX     pos

0       0        0.375 -0.50 -1 0

1       1        0.375  0.50 -1 0

2       2       -0.375 -0.50 -1 0

3       3       -0.375  0.50 -1 0

but the view is empty.

What confuses me is the W value of 0, how does perspective division work with a zero value? or does it just discard the vertex (which would explain why we see nothing)?

Again, if we switch off the perspective matrix (so everything is identity) the quad is displayed correctly and we see the vertices in the `VS Out` view (with W=1 in this case) - so there must be some culling going on but what?

**EDIT3:** - simulating depth:

Another suggestion was to simulate depth using a simple matrix to make doubly sure that the problem lies with the perspective calculation and that the rest of the code works fine.

I bodged a per-frame uniform update that spins and expands the quad over a 5 second period:

```java
final float t = (System.currentTimeMillis() % 5000L) / 5000f;

final Matrix scale = new Matrix.Builder()
    .identity()
    .set(0, 0, t)
    .set(1, 1, t)
    .build();

final Matrix rot = Matrix.rotation(Vector.Z_AXIS, t * MathsUtil.HALF_PI);

final ByteBuffer bb = BufferFactory.byteBuffer(uniform.length());
final FloatBuffer fb = bb.asFloatBuffer();

scale.buffer(fb);
rot.buffer(fb);

uniform.push(bb);
```

Again this works perfectly!

**EDIT4**: Finally, some progress!

So following on from suggestions I have analysed what's going on with RenderDoc (excellent tool btw!). The uniforms and vertex/index buffers look fine, the textures are all good, matrices seem to be in the right order, etc.

But I still couldn't work out why we were seeing W=0 for any vertices with a depth of zero after the vertex shader. So I sort of reverse engineered the maths and came to the conclusion that the perspective matrix **had** to be missing something so I fiddled the bottom-right value (originally zero) to 1 and things now started to work a lot better!

```java
final float range = near - far;
return new Matrix.Builder()
    .set(0, 0, 1f / (height * dim.ratio()))
    .set(1, 1, 1f / height)
    .set(2, 2, far / range * 0.5f)
    .set(3, 2, -1)
    .set(3, 2, (near * far) / range * 0.5f)
    .set(3, 3, 1)                                   // <---- fiddled
    .build();
```

From here we were able to load the chalet OBJ model and got that working relatively quickly.

Also managed to plug in an orbit camera controlled by the mouse and can now rotate around the chalet model, sweet.

However I still feel that I'm missing something - why does fiddling the perspective matrix work? why do none of the examples I've seen have a 1 there? and if not how on earth does perspective division work for those examples? Still confused!

Comment: Can you also add your pipeline setup, the viewport state (which includes min and max depths) and the code and structures you use to pass matrix data to the shader? So we can rule out other problems like culling or wrong padding. If all of these are fine, you may want to run your sample through RenderDoc, and check the Mesh View before and after data is run through the vertex shader and make sure that data is properly passed.

Comment: The w component is used for the perspective division, having this set to 0.0 will project the vertex to infinity, which would explain your triangle being occasionally partially visible if e.g. rotating or scaling it.

If you properly pass vertices in with ```w = 1.0f``` and get an output with ```w = 0.0f```, then your perspective matrix is the problem. Make sure that it's a proper one where ```wc = {0, 0, 1, 0}```.
You may also want to check if the matrices are properly passed to the shader using RenderDoc.

Comment: Sanity check - are you definitely uploading the matrix in the right memory order (e.g. you're not expecting column_major, and actually getting row_major?)

Comment: Just checked the matrices in RenderDoc and they look correct (or at least they are the same as the ones generated on the Java side).  RD specifically states they are column major ordered.

Comment: @SaschaWillems Not sure what you mean by wc = {0, 0, 1, 0}, are you referring to a row or column of the projection matrix?

Comment: Made some progress, see EDIT #4 above. Would be great if some kind soul (who happened to have some related code to hand) could dump out some example perspective / camera matrices for comparison. As I said, using Java so hard for me to compare vs GLM.

Comment: Here are the matrices from my [Vulkan C++ triangle example](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/tree/master/examples/triangle) with the camera moved -1 on the z axis.

Projection is calculated via glm as ```glm::perspective(glm::radians(60.0f), (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 256.0f);```:

![RenderDoc vertex shader inputs](https://www.saschawillems.de/images/2019-04-04_22_28_31-Window.png)